# Why are there two different syntaxes for azure-pipeline system variables?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, system-variable

As the ADO documenation on using system variables in pipeline conditions is not very clear, I came here to find an answer. But I found two.

`condition: eq(variables.buildSourceBranchName, 'main')`

and

`condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'main')`

give me the same result. Is there any difference? I so what is that difference?

Comment: Have you looked through these docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax

Comment: I did. That sec;tion lists all fo the pre-defined variables and how to use them in a bash or powershell. But there is no indication of the syntax to use to refer to those variables within the YAML. 
I found the two variations of the syntax described above in answere here on stackoverflow.